# Attempting to implement IOS Layout

Tags: ios, swift, layout, storyboard

Hello everyone I have coded an app for android and I am currently porting it to IOS. Here is the sketch of the layout how I want it to input. I have coded everything in Xcode but the layout. I am very stuck. Resetting to suggested constraints will not work here. I know IOS does not have a weight system

As you can see I have 4 objects. A title, textfield, button and a custom object view. The custom object view can only be added via swift code, so no storyboard support there. Also the button needs to be pinned inside the corner of the text field.

Edit************Also at the top of the screen is a navigation controller********

[image: Sketch]

Comment: You can normally add custom controls in storyboard by just adding a UIView and setting the custom class. Is 'Input' a text field or a text view?  I am assuming you mean text view. You wouldn't put the button in the text view in iOS. It would go under it

Comment: What constraints have you tried? What specific layout issue are you facing?

Comment: hey thanks for the repsonse! Input is a text field.  I have tried setting equal height constraints and then using a multiplier but it does not work (the layout doesn't adjust). I have also tried using constraints to the margin and to each object, but then items are pushed off the page.